# Problem building rosjava-core - rosjava_core:unspecified

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to build rosjava_core by invoking ./gradlew

I'm running kubuntu 13.04, and have installed ros-hydro-desktop-full from the repos.

I've cloned rosjava_core from the git repo, and switched to the hydro branch.

this is the error I am getting.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'rosjava_core'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find any version that matches org.ros.rosjava_bootstrap:gradle_plugins:[0.1,0.2).
     Required by:
         :rosjava_core:unspecified
```

On a side note, all I actually want to do is start writing a java node. Am I starting in the wrong place?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/108091/problem-building-rosjava-core---rosjava_core:unspecified/) by [rlsutton1](https://answers.ros.org/users/9666/rlsutton1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-12-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a set of 3 tutorials [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rosjava). The first explains the installation. You don't even need to build rosjava from source, you can get deb packages for it. If you want to do it from source, there are also a few more steps to it, as explained in the tutorial.

<del>The following two tutorials should (in theory) get you running with your first rosjava package, but at the moment there seem to be bugs. But that's a question for another day... :)</del>

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2013-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rlsutton1](https://answers.ros.org/users/9666/rlsutton1/) on 2013-12-09**:
Thank you very much, problem solved.

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2013-12-09**:
Should be bug free - we've been using those instructions unchanged for a month or two now. If there's bugs (or perhaps missing documentation), please post!

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-12-10**:
@Daniel Stonier: sorry for the false alarm. I tried Tutorial 2 ("creating rosjava packages") yesterday and failed; today, it worked. Turns out I was too stupid for copy-paste, and instead of `cd rosjava_foo; catkin_create_rosjava_project dude` I did `cd rosjava; ...`. :o)

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2013-12-11**:
Awesome :)

**Comment by [aknirala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1931/aknirala/) on 2013-12-16**:
I'm trying to test ROSJAVA on 12.04 with hydro, but 'Creating Rosjava Packages' in above tutorial give error

```
:foo_msgs:jar
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not copy MANIFEST.MF to '/home/aknirala/rosjava/src/rosjava_foo/foo_msgs/build/tmp/jar/MANIFEST.MF'

**Comment by [aknirala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1931/aknirala/) on 2013-12-16**:
Any suggestion on how to fix this?
A silly question: Do I need to install gradle separately?

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2013-12-16**:
You might like to start a new question aknirala. I just took that information out of that particular tutorial so it 'works'. The next tutorial on unofficial messages is more relevant for highlighting about msg project generation.

**Comment by [aknirala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1931/aknirala/) on 2013-12-18**:
Thnx, I started learning gradle (as I figure out it will be v helpful). It seems it is gradle issue, or I'll be able to easily identify it once I know gradle.... If possible please update the tutorial by adding info on what you remove to run it error free. I'll do it once I figure that out.

**Comment by [csy2033](https://answers.ros.org/users/10071/csy2033/) on 2013-12-19**:
I was having the same problem. but setting export ROS_MAVEN_REPOSITORY=https://github.com/stonier/rosjava_mvn_repo/raw/master and JAVA_HOME fixed it for me without installing ros-hydro desktop..

**Comment by [aknirala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1931/aknirala/) on 2013-12-28**:
It seems the tutorials have been updated (many many thnx for that). However I am not able to use custom messages and services from ROSJAVA. I have asked this at: http://answers.ros.org/question/113551/using-custom-messages-and-service-in-rosjava/ 
Kindly hep.